# What is the meaning of AOSP's 'lunch' combinations and what do I need to choose?

Tags: android, build, arm, 64-bit, android-source

I am a new comer to Android devices ROM development. Anyway, I am now in the progress of building AOSP to a Chinese device with a 64-bit processor. I am following the menu at source.android.com, and when I am running the "lunch" command, the terminal says: "Lunch menu... pick a combo:".

There are two options of which I am debating: aosp_arm-eng and aosp_arm64_eng.

As I have mentioned, I am building for a 64-bit processor device. Does it mean that I need to pick the aosp_arm64-eng? Because I have tried it, but then the emulator didn't work for some reason...

Answer (score 11):

Those names are constructed, on the fly, by the build system.  They reflect the specific device builds in the `$AOSP/device` directory (specifically, by running the the `vendorsetup.sh` files in the subdirectories).

The portion of the name before the hyphen ('-') is the target hardware. The portion after the hyphen is one of `eng`, `userdebug`, and `release`.  Those keywords control the debugging tools added to the build and whether adbd runs as root or not.

Both `aosp_arm-eng` and `aosp_arm64_eng` should produce a useful emulator.  Neither, however, will work on your device.  For your device you will need a specific, customized, build.  If there isn't one already available, creating it can be quite time consuming.

Comment: The $AOSP/device directory is worth repeating.  As well as $AOSP/vendor and $AOSP/product,  The lunch menu is populated from any `vendorsetup.sh` files found under these three directories.  For a clean pull of master, `$AOSP/device` is the only one of these three that has these files.

Answer (score 7):

(two years later)

This answer is just to update the prior answer further.  The "lunch" menu combos are made up of two **or three** fields.  The first two are as stated above and repeated here:

1. The first field (the portion up to the first hyphen '-') is the target hardware (exported as TARGET_PRODUCT).
2. The second field (the portion following the first hyphen, up to the optional second hypen, or end of line) is one of the keywords, `eng`, `userdebug`, `release` (exported as TARGET_BUILD_VARIANT).
3. The third (optional) field (the portion following the optional second hypen) is the version (if present, it's exported as TARGET_PLATFORM_VERSION).

Not all possible lunch combos are listed though.  The most notable one is `sdk-eng` and variants.  This one sets up the build system so that you can build the different SDKs, for instance:

```
    lunch sdk-eng
    make -j8 win_sdk
```

Comment: Do you know where I could get full list of TARGET_PRODUCT in the aosp project? I searched many places, but still couldn't get it. And analyzing the aosp's building system is also a huge task for me currently! Thanks in advacne!

Comment: @ClockZHONG In AOSP 13, the list of available products can be found by searching for `PRODUCT_MAKEFILE` : `find -name *.mk | xargs grep PRODUCT_MAKEFILE`